# Reading a JSON response from REST API always returns empty text

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api

I hope all is well and I appreciate if you can help me or re-direct me to a similar old post because I couldn't find one.

I'm trying to initiate a REST API request and the server will send a JSON response. The request works find but I'm unable to read the JSON output. The status always returns 0.

Here is my code.

---

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {

   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("POST", "URL HERE", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")     
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = response.Result;


}
</script>
```

I want to print this JSON's result:

```
{ 
  Meta: { 
    Status: 'Success',
    Debug: ''
  },
  Result: { 
    Count: 2584,
    Error: [],
    Info: [],
    Skipped: [],
    DuplicateResponseCount: 0,
    DuplicateError: null
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1

Comment: You are making an asynchronous request, so the response is not there when your code is trying to get it

Comment: Should I change to: xhttp.open("POST", "URL HERE", false)?

Comment: @Asma Nope, asynchronous request are a good thing. Otherwise you'll just block the browser for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález, I didn't know the difference. Now I realized what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pablo said. You are using asynchronous. One option is use get method or just pass a callback to the function.

```
function _post(url, callback) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", url, true);

  xhttp.onload = function() {
    if (xhttp.status === 200) callback(xhttp.responseText);
    else callback("error");
  };
  xhttp.send();

  return xhttp.responseText;
}

_post("url here", function callback(response) {
  // you can access response in here.
  console.log(response);
});
```

On your PHP script

```
<?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: Thanks, Lara. I tried the code but it didn't work and I got an "error" message. Previously, I was a able to post the data but I got blank response but now the data wasn't actually posted, though the URL is correct.

Comment: @Asma you get error because of the xhttp status is not 200. Maybe its 404. I used this for my API. Try using `callback(xhttp.status) in onload function`. :)

Comment: Thanks again. I tried it and it returned "403" "Forbidden", so does that suggest that the server is rejecting my request?

Comment: @Asma did you try to add header in PHP?

Comment: Thanks Lara. I investigated further about the same origin policy and it appears that it was causing the problem. I found out that the server supports JSONP so I'm trying now in this direction. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Asma You're welcome. I'm glad I helped you :) Happy coding.